# What is the proper way to render a json array dynamically in Vuejs template?

Tags: javascript, json, vuejs2, vuex

I need to display an array of json data that I fetched from the server:

Using `v-for` directive i should be able to create a Card for each data.

I am using Vuex to get and data the JSON data. I use `computed` to get the data in Vue component, every thing work fine at this level.

```js
<template>
    <b-row>
        <b-col v-for="company in processCompanies" :key="company.id" cols="2">
            <div>
                <b-card :title="company.companyAcronym" :sub-title="company.companyAcronym">
                    <b-card-text>{{company.dateRegistered}}</b-card-text>
                    <b-link href="#" :id="company._id" class="card-link" @click="$emit('changeComponent','CompanyDetails')">Manage</b-link>
                </b-card>
            </div>
        </b-col>  
    </b-row>  
</template>

computed: {
    ...mapGetters({companies: 'company/getCompanies'}),
    processCompanies: function(){
        return this.companies;
    }
}
```

Instead of having one card created dynamically from the JSON Data, I ended up having 117 cards created.

Is there any problem with my `v-for` directive, or what is  proper way of doing the rendering with the json data above?

```
[{"_id":"Pg76sjvQ5XWxD8OZ20qyfOOhqP23","companyAcronym":"JABIQ","dateRegistered":"2019-05-13T01:35:45.292Z","__v":0}]
```

Comment: Change `:key="company.id"` to `:key="company._id"` this gives Vue a way to detect if the array entries have changed or not.

Comment: I have made the change as you said, but the cards are still the same number 117 instead of 1.

Comment: Nothing seems to be wrong with your Vue file then. The vuex store could be where the data is getting duplicated. Could you log the value of the getter in the store and see how many entries exist?

Comment: Here is my action in the store and the log shows the current state of the object as having one json data:)      this.$axios.$get(herokuUrl)
      .then(function (response) {
        let data = JSON.stringify(response);
        vuexContext.commit('setCompanies',data);
        console.log("companies:"+vuexContext.state.companies)
    })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("companies fails to load")
      })
      .finally(function () {
      });

Comment: Try placing the `v-for` in `b-card` instead of `b-col`.

Comment: After replacing v-for in b-card, the cards layout  now is in a least form.

Comment: After replacing v-for in b-card, the cards layout  now is in a list form. I am suspecting this to be from the Computed property of  Vue. If i manually copy the json and assign it to a data property like this works:)   data() {
      return {
        compayData: 
 
 [{"_id":"Pg76sjvQ5XWxD8OZ20qyfOOhqP23","companyAcronym":"JABIQ","dateRegistered":"2019-05-13T01:35:45.292Z","__v":0}]
      }
    }

Comment: I have checkout the json data and found out that, every character is rendered as a card => json =117 -charcaters = 117 cards. This makes me to understand that there is a problem with the list rendering, when the data is served from compute property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on you getting 117 cards instead of one, and you having exactly 117 characters in your response, it seems clear that you're treating the response as a `String` instead of object.

you can fix this by adding `JSON.parse(response)` somewhere along the way before you try to render it.

if you're using `axios`, and you're getting this response, it's likely due to server setting the wrong encoding information.

if you're using `fetch`, the response does not get converted automatically, but it's easy to parse the response with addition of `then(r => JSON.parse(r))`

If you post your ajax call code, it would be easier to make a suggestion though.